# Django Rest Framework Analytics

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, analytics

I've been searching the internet for hours and can't find answer so this is my last resort.

Do you guys have any idea what's the best way to capture how much a user has sent let's say get request for a specific endpoint? I also want it to be distinguishable by whether the user sent a request on a mobile app or on a website (the same endpoint).

I thought about making a model something like:

```
class Visit(models.Model)
    product = models.ForeignKey('Product')
    user = models.ForeignKey('User')
    on_mobile = models.BooleanField(default='False')
    on_website = models.BooleanField(default='False')
    times_visit = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

and shooting

```
if Visit.objects.get(user=self.request.user, product=self.kwargs['pk']).exists():
    times_visit += 1 
Visit.objects.create(user=self.request.user, product=self.kwargs['pk'])
```

Do you have any idea how "check" whether user sent it through mobile app or website?
Or maybe there is some other better way?
I would be thankful for any kind of help.

Answer (score 0):

You should parse user agent. There is some library for that.

I use this library.

https://pypi.org/project/user-agents/